# Dynamically disabling touch-action (overscroll) for SVG elements

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome, svg, touch

I'm having problems with touch screen overscrolling on Chrome.

I have a document with am SVG element in it, which contains some shape, say a rectangle:

[image]

Now, I want to make the rectangle draggable, which means that I want to disable all kinds of touch actions on the respective `<rect>` element, by setting it's style property `touch-action: none`.

This works fine on all desktop browsers, except Chrome. On Chrome, when I touch and move on a rectangle, browser's overscroll feature kicks in. This causes the browser window to awkwardly move, as well as all Pointer events that I have set on the rectangle cancelled.

I.e. `pointermove` is registered for a fraction of second, then it just stops when overscroll kicks in. `pointerup` is never called even when touch is released.

[image]

Now, if I had an HTML element instead of an SVG element, setting `touch-action: none` would do the job. The same thing on an SVG element fails.

Technically, this could be solved by either setting `touch-action: none` on `document.body` or wrapping the whole SVG into a `<div>` element with `touch-action: none` set.

Unfortunately, that is not an option for me since I need the document (and rest of the rectangle-surrounding SVG) to retain all of its original touch gestures, except when directly on a rectangle.

As a solution, I did try to dynamically set `touch-action: none` on `document: body` when `pointerdown` event occurs on a rectangle.

```
// Get element
var o = document.getElementById( "test" );

// disable touch action on press of the SVG element
o.addEventListener( "pointerdown", function(e) {
  document.body.style.touchAction = "none";
} );

// re-enable touch action when released
o.addEventListener( "pointerup", function(e) {
  document.body.style.touchAction = "auto";
} );
```

Unfortunately, that does not help. The style on body gets set and next time I try dragging rectangle it works as expected (because `pointerup` event never gets executed), just not this time.

Adding `preventDefault()` to event handlers has also no effect.

I would appreciate if someone who have had similar experience could share a solution.

Here's a live example of the above.

```js
// Get element
var o = document.getElementById( "test" );

// disable touch action on press of the SVG element
o.addEventListener( "pointerdown", function(e) {
  document.body.style.touchAction = "none";
} );

// re-enable touch action when released
o.addEventListener( "pointerup", function(e) {
  document.body.style.touchAction = "auto";
} );
```

```html
<svg id="test" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" style="width: 300px; height: 300px; border: 1px solid #eee;">
  <g transform="translate(50,50)">
    <rect fill="#00fff0" width="200" height="200" style="touch-action: none;"></rect>
  </g>
</svg>
```

---

UPDATE: looks like using `preventDefault()` on an `touchstart` event does the trick.

However, it seems to be wrong to use **both** modern `pointerdown` and legacy `touchstart` at the same time. This seems like a bug in Chrome 60. If anyone could confirm it, that would be great.

Comment: Is the example supposed to work only with touch screens? I can't move your rectangle. By the way, have you tried to `preventDefault` the event which triggers the pan when the rectangle is being pressed?

Comment: Yes, it's relevant for touch screens only. And, for simplicity sake the code to actually move the rectangle is not there, because it's beyond the point. Also, yes, I did try `preventDefault()` - thanks for reminding me that, I'll update the question

Comment: In which events did you _prevented_?

Comment: @lilezek `pointerdown`

Comment: Hm, looks like having `preventDefault()` in a `touchstart` event does the trick. Seems wrong to have `both `touchstart` and `pointerdown` just to prevent this :(

Comment: I think you should also try CSS `pointer-events: none` and `user-select: none`; I know it's the touch events you are aiming to disable, but there could be a chrome behavior that relies on these events as well.

Answer (score 3):

I think it would be enough by preventing `touchstart`:

```
window.addEventListener( "touchstart", function(e) {
  // Determine wether or not you are panning from rectangle:
  if (e.target ....)
      e.preventDefault();
} );
```

Comment: There's no such event `pandown`, or am I missing something?

Comment: I'm sorry, I was wrong. pandown is an ionic event. You have to use touchstart.

Comment: Gotcha. Updated my question. Seems like touchstart does the trick. However, it seems so wrong to be using both events just to work around Chrome's feature, or is it a bug?

Comment: Do you mean both `pointerdown` and `touchstart`? Are you sure you need to prevent `pointerdown` too?

Comment: I need to capture `pointerdown` event for a lot of other activities. Naturally, I would prefer to `preventDefault()` in it, rather than have a separate `touchstart` for it.

Comment: Maybe you can change pointerdown for touchstart for everything. If you can't, then I don't see any problem with using one and preventing the other.